# Is there any way to instantiate multiple static sections within a page for Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm fairly new to liquid and Shopify development, but I'm making my way through. I've hit a snag where it seems like what I want to accomplish isn't possible. I'm making a static article page that's primarily HTML, but scattered throughout, I'd like to include instances of a relevant "You Might Like" section to display products.

```
<HTML>
{% section 'youMightLike' %}
<HTML>
{% section 'youMightLike' %}
```

I've tried adding a "presets" in the schema tag, and while that allows my section code to be placed anywhere on the homepage and function the way I think it should, my static page only allows for one collection to be chosen (which is then applied to every section on the page).

I've also tried adding blocks to the schema so I could just choose the collection in the block, but that seems to consolidate all the {% section 'youMightLike' %} lines across my entire page.

Am I thinking about this the right way, or is there something else I should be looking into?

Answer (score 1):

Provided your theme is Online Store 2.0 capable, all you need is a unique page template and then you can just add whatever sections are necessary via the customizer.

If it's just a general page or what have you, break your HTML into a section or sections you can include on the page and then you can move around as needed https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/sections

If your theme isn't 2.0 capable, then you can just create additional sections by modifying them slightly so they're *unique*. Just copy the section and then modify the name somehow so it's not the same.